# How do I load existing typescript file from another script to improve performance?

Tags: typescript, lazy-loading

I have a TypeScript file where I catch the events happening on the DOM and send data streams to AWS Kinesis. I am currently using that script in my HTML for test as,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./tracker.ts?projectId=123&apiKey=trac3ab1e-50fa-50b5-dab5-acce55e5cafe"></script>
```

I have used parcel to create bundle so don't think I am attaching `ts` file on html.

After `npm run dev` the `<script>` changes to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./tracker.568463.js?projectId=123&apiKey=trac3ab1e-50fa-50b5-dab5-acce55e5cafe"></script>
```

`tracker.ts` has a class `Tracker`, inside which I have also loaded AWS SDK, and sent data streams to Kinesis.

I want to load this `tracker.ts` from another script. I have few confusion.

- How can it be implemented?
- How feasible would that be?
- How will it effect the performance?

For implementation I have tried few things

First, I changed `type="application/javascript"` in `<script>` to `type="module"`, [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading#Strategies), this was not helpful and also some part of code was not read.

Second, I am trying to import `tracker.ts`'s `Tracker` class as module from [this reference](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/project/modules/external-modules), but I am confused on how it might be implemented it my case. I am also getting a warning saying `tracker.ts` is not a module.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are really confused.
First, you can't load TypeScript files directly.
you'll need to compile the typescript code to javascript that the browser can understand.
Second, you tried to load tracker.ts with params(?projectId=123&apiKey=trac3ab1e-50fa-50b5-dab5-acce55e5cafe)
You can't do this.
You can do this if you are loading an external resource that is on the internet.
I really recommend learning the basics before trying a thing such as AWS kinetic.

#### compiling TypeScript

Run in the terminal:
`npm install tsc`
then run:
`tsc tracker.ts`
Then, you will see a tracker.js file.
Then load this file.

#### About the params:

Instead of using params:

before the tracker.js script loading, add this:

```
<script>
window.projectId = 'somethin'
window.apiKey = 'somethin'
</script>
```

Then, in the tracker file, you can access this like this:

```
const projected = window.projectId;
const apiKey = window.apiKey
```

**NOTE:** after changing tracker.ts, run `tsc tracker.ts` again, so the changes will reflect tracker.js

Comment: This is just a Test Project, for compiling I have used Parcel, which creates bundle.

Comment: I understand. parcel does not compile TypeScript by default.

Comment: Please do not worry about that, after `npm run dev`, the index.html will have js file attached. `src="tracker.6546546.js?projectId=123&apiKey=trac3ab1e-50fa-50b5-dab5-acce55e5cafe"`

Comment: Oh, sorry. 
But you can't load scripts with params like ?projectId.
In my answer, I showed you how to overcome this.

Comment: I do not think that would be a problem, because I have a method to parse everything from that scripts query string, the main problem here is, I want a different file to be attached on the main page, which will then load `tracker` file later.

Comment: Also it's not AWS Kinetic it's AWS Kinesis :D

Comment: Try this:
`
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'your src';
`

Comment: Yeah, Kinesis :)